# Android layout design: layout.xml vs dimens.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I am a newbie android developer. Recently I am reading Google's specification of providing alternative resources to support different screen size.

> https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

I know we can provide resource directories with specific qualifiers to achieve this,

e.g. `layout-sw320dp/layout.xml`,`layout-sw480dp/layout.xml`, `layout-sw600dp/layout.xml`.

Meanwhile, I also found some developers who create various`dimens.xml` in the `values` folders with different screen size qualifiers,

e.g. `values-sw320dp/dimens.xml` , `values-sw480dp/dimens.xml`, `values-sw600dp/dimens.xml`.

I am wondering which approach would be better for maintaining the layout. My intuition told me if I have controlled the screen size rendering by different `layout.xml`. Then I do not need to use `dimens.xml` to fit different screen size. Is it a right thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use dimens.xml if the only thing changing is the size.  You should use layout.xml if you're changing the actual views.

Why?  Because of maintenance.  If in 3 months you decide you want to change the background color of a view and you have 4 layout files, you need to go and change it in 4 places.  Eventually you'll forget one.  If you used dimens properly, you only need to change it in 1 place.

Prefer to use dimens wherever possible.

Comment: what if i need to add language qualifier for my `string.xml` as well? do I have to put several identical 'string.xml` to the values folder? e.g. `values-fr-sw320dp/string.xml`, `values-fr-sw480dp/string.xml`, `values-fr-sw600dp/string.xml`. I cannot avoid such duplication, right? thanks in advance!

Comment: @jackyflau Size based strings files would be extremely unusual. What use case do you have for changing the string being displayed based on the size of the screen? If you aren't changing the screen size, then a single values-fr/string.xml would be sufficient

Comment: I actually do not need to change the string based on screen size. it should be changed based on users' language setting. so how should i set the values folder in a proper way? I want dimens.xml contolled by screen size while string.xml controlled by language setting, but the two xml files are both in values folder

Comment: @jackycflau values/string.xml should hold english.  values-fr/string.xml should hold french.  That's all you need.  Then you can use @string/some_name in your layouts or resources.getString(R.string.some_name) in your code and it will grab the correct version based on locale.

Comment: so that means android will pick two values folders at them same time, e.g. values-fr/ and values-sw320dp? I originally think that it will only pick one value folder only for each time

Comment: @jackycflau Yes.  It all works on an override system.  It takes the most specific one that exists.  If it doesn't exist, it falls back to the less specific version.  It isn't working by picking a folder and looking for everything there